# NPOI produces unreadable content

Tags: excel, apache-poi, npoi

I'm using NPOI to open an existing Excel file, make modifications, and write it back to disk.

However, when I open the file with NPOI and write it back, the file becomes damaged. Excel complains that the file "contains unreadable content", and asks whether I want to "recover the contents" of the file. When I select OK, it says:

```
Excel cannot open the file 'test.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.
```

Here is my code:

```
        var excelFilename = "c:\\temp\\simplefile.xlsx";
        IWorkbook wb;
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(excelFilename))
        {
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
        }
        var sheet = wb.GetSheetAt(0);
        // For this sample, we don't make any modifications to the file.
        // Just opening and writing it back is enough to produce this error.
        using (var str = new FileStream(excelFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            wb.Write(str);
        }
```

"simplefile.xlsx" is an empty excel workbook created by Excel 2010.
What's happening here?

Comment: I would try `var str = new FileStream(excelFilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)` since the workbook should overwrite the whole file and using `FileMode.Open`: [For an existing file, it does not append the new text to the existing text. Instead, it overwrites the existing characters with the new characters. If you overwrite a longer string ... with a shorter string ..., the file will contain a mix of the strings ...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this: There are other circumstances where NPOI produces unreadable files. For example, when you save a file in Excel with filters active. De-activate any filters in Excel before saving - otherwise NPOI may produce unreadable files.

Comment: Please submit your corrupted Excel problem with NPOI to https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/issues